# Does MS Exchange OWA support settings for how to render received plain text mails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, fonts, exchange

I needed to migrate my mail workflow from using an external mail client with POP3/IMAP/SMTP (The Bat!) to Exchange based OWA, which is web-based. I regularly receive plain text monitoring emails designed to be best read with fonts like Courier New and sizes depending on the available screen width, resolution, and stuff, which people can simply configure in their mail client mainly. That doesn't seem to be possible anymore with OWA, and I seem to can only configure fonts and sizes for outgoing mails, which doesn't make too much sense anyway because I'm sending plain text mostly. The following is an example of how such email was rendered in the past vs. now:

[image: screenshot good rendering]

Vs.

[image: screenshot bad rendering]

It doesn't even look that bad when looking at the table in the dev-tools of Firefox:

[image: screenshot dev-tools rendering]

It seems like the problem is mainly the wrong font not using fixed width per character. Is there some way to change that in the settings I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

There's at least some workaround by [injecting custom CSS](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/styl-us/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) using some browser extension or alike:

```css
#Item\.MessageUniqueBody .PlainText
{
  font-family: 'Courier New' !important;
}
```

The backslash is important, because the ID really is that way and `.` must not be interpreted as part of some additional selector class name or alike.

Answer (score 0):

> Does MS Exchange OWA support settings for how to render received plain text mails?

I am afraid No. There's no such an option available in Exchange OWA to adjust how to render incoming plain text mails.

You can submit this as a feature request via the official feedback portal: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/